# insert on duplicate update с подготовленным запросом

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, pdo

```
$info = array('1','2','3'); //первое значение уникальное
//в таблице row1 тоже уникальное
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tabl` (`row1`,`row2`,`row3`) VALUES (?,?,?) on duplicate key UPDATE `row2` = ?, `row3` = ?";
$prepare = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$prepare->execute($info);
```

Не могу понять, почему не работает

Comment: потому что знаков вопроса пять, а значений в массиве три? ну и  к тому же какой смысл вложен в `UPDATE \`row2\` = ?, \`row3\` = ?` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский их нужно обновить при повторном row1

Comment: почему бы не писать `\`row2\` = VALUES(row2), \`row3\` = VALUES(row3)"` ?

Comment: Если в таблице `tabl` нет других полей, кроме `row1`,`row2`,`row3` - используйте `REPLACE INTO`.

Comment: Второй день думаю над Вашим предложением, @Akina, но не могу понять - а в чем именно преимущество этого? Из того что я прочитал единственное их различие только в том что replace сначала удаляет запись, а потом вставляет её, вызывая соответствующие триггеры. При этом логично, что данный способ мало того что применим только в особых случаях, так еще и работает медленнее.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский Скорость работы при вставке/замене одной записи (а в коде используется вовсе не пакетная обработка) неважна. Применимость `REPLACE` ничуть не уже, чем `INSERT ... ODKU` - если знать о его существовании. В данном конкретном случае с указанными мной ограничениями он вообще лучше, во всяком случае дублирование параметров в `INSERT ... ODKU` не на руку понимабельности. Если же на таблице имеются триггеры - они с большой долей вероятности вообще сделают `INSERT ... ODKU` и `REPLACE` неэквивалентными, и вопрос замены одного другим отпадёт, не появившись.

Comment: @Akina, ну Алексей Шиманский же предложил - использовать стандартный `row2 = VALUES(row2), row3 = VALUES(row3)`, никакие параметры в этом случае не дублируются. Просто после предложенного хорошо работающего решения Вы предлагаете использовать то, что не лучше (а по скорости еще и чуть хуже). Так что, повторюсь, чем лучше? Вы если что-то хитрое знаете - так поделитесь, я же вопрос задаю. Я допускаю, что чего-то могу не знать - я вообще про `REPLACE` узнал только вчера.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский *я вообще про REPLACE узнал только вчера* Из моего комментария, что ли? ну вот, значит хоть какая-то польза от него уже есть... Опять же - если есть альтернатива, почему надо о ней молчать? Автор решит, проигнорировать или попробовать, а если попробует, то по итогам определит, что ему больше подходит.